# Reduce a data frame by combining like rows according to two qualitative factors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
observations<- data.frame(X=c("00KS089001","00KS089001","00KS089002","00KS089002","00KS089003","00KS089003","00KS105001","00KS105001", "00KS177011","00KS177011","00P0006","00P006","00P006","00P006"), hzdept = c(0,20,0,15,0,13,0,20,0,16,0,6,13,29), hzdepb = c(20,30,15,30,13,30,20,30,16,30,6,13,29,30),Y=c("Red","White","Red","White","Green","Red","Red","Blue", "Black","Black","Red","White","White","White"), Z = c(0.67,0.33,0.5,0.5,0.43,0.57,0.67,0.33,0.53,0.47,0.2,0.23,0.53,0.04))
```

I want to be able to reduce this so that anytime X and Y are the same for two rows, the observations are combined i.e.

```
data.frame(X=c("00KS089001","00KS089001","00KS089002","00KS089002","00KS089003","00KS089003","00KS105001","00KS105001", "00KS177011","00P0006","00P006"), hzdept = c(0,20,0,15,0,13,0,20,0,0,6), hzdepb = c(20,30,15,30,13,30,20,30,30,6,30),Y=c("Red","White","Red","White","Green","Red","Red","Blue", "Black","Red","White"), Z = c(0.67,0.33,0.5,0.5,0.43,0.57,0.67,0.33,1.00,0.20,0.80))
```

Any suggestions on how to best go about this?

Comment: how do you want to combine them? how you get your z values is not obvious

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a typo in the Z column; should be more intuitive to see. What I want is to combine them s.t. the hzdept becomes the smallest value in the grouping of like rows, hzdepb becomes the largest value, and Z becomes the sum of all Z's in the group.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: ok, now that I see how `hzdept` and `hzdepb` are supposed to be combined from your commment above:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- observations %>% count(X,Y,wt = Z,name = "Z")

df_hzdept <- observations %>%
   arrange(hzdept) %>%
   distinct(X,Y,.keep_all = T) %>%
   select(X,Y,hzdept)

df_hzdepb <- observations %>%
   arrange(desc(hzdepb)) %>%
   distinct(X,Y,.keep_all = T) %>%
   select(X,Y,hzdepb)

df <- df %>% left_join(df_hzdept) %>% left_join(df_hzdepb)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using dplyr**

Here is how you would group by two columns and summarize using the minimum, max, and sum other columns in a dataframe:

```
library(magrittr) # For the pipe: %>% 
observations %>%
    dplyr::group_by(X, Y) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(hzdept  = min(hzdept),
                     hzdepb  = max(hzdepb),
                     Z = sum(Z), .groups = 'drop')
```